# w3tc Minified CSS + CDN Issue

Tags: wordpress, cdn, rackspace-cloud, w3-total-cache

This is a weird one.

I have a Wordpress site with w3 Total Cache, and I have Rackspace cloud files set up to serve my static site content.  Unfortunately, on the most recent push, my CSS is like jumbled machine code.  Check this out:

http://cdn.thoughtspacedesigns.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/VYtBDsIwDAQ_1NqkQkLiHXwgBCuNceoQJyr9PYjCgePOzM6tlTOiZ_-EqBqFfEkGQfOHoaSrIT861Q0dnGD6DshpAbbhgPzzQN62oNLz8s8tVBW56OjgCNP4fu7aUqM9GRwyteLDHbPeupDhWmLVWV8.js

That's my minified javascript file on the CDN.  I don't know what's wrong.  I've tried to purge the files from the CDN with the same results.  I've had to turn off the CDN functionality in w3tc for now.  Any ideas?

Comment: That file is not found for me. Although, I think I did have a similar problem to this recently. Is it where the minified files are filled with strange characters?

Comment: Yes exactly.  It's just garbage info.

Comment: Are you uploading it using just an API key? I was also using Rackspace files and I remember having to set up FTP for it instead which made it work. Is that a road you've gone down yet?

Comment: I've been using the API key area in w3 total cache.  I've not played with FTP and would prefer not too because the file handling in w3tc I find much more elegant and simplified

Comment: Was FTP the only method you found to fix the issue?  Is this an underlying issue with w3 Total Cache?

Comment: Yeah. I did have this exact problem you're having and couldn't find a reason for it. One option was that I could use FTP which I was able to get working but as you say, not elegant! So instead I left cache off manually compressed my CSS and loaded my scripts asynchronously.

Comment: Unfortunately that's seeming like the way I may have to go.  I wish there were a better way.  Maybe time to look into another CDN provider :/